# How to start and stop application in tomcat using java?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I developed simple web application "myapplication". and i deployed into Tomcat 6.0.29.

The application stopped, when i execute this "http://localhost:8080/manager/stop?path=/myapplication"

Is possible to start the application using java program?
Is possible to stop the application using java program?

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

---

Not working in Windows. It works in linux ubuntu

I got error, when use

```
Process p = r.exec("wget http://tomcatusername:tomcatepassword@localhost:8080/manager/stop?path=/myapplication -O - -q");
```

Error is :

```
Error occur: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wget": 
CreateProcess error=2, The Stystem cannot find the file specified
```

Anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Process p = r.exec("wget http://tomcatusername:tomcatepassword@localhost:8080/manager/stop?path=/myapplication -O - -q");
```

Answer (score 0):

No way for standard java net library.

Try to use library *org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient* this code works for Tomcat 7

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://" + host + ":" + port + "/manager/text/" + action + "?path=/" + app);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(host, Integer.valueOf(port)),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 2000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 2000);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```